SymPy not finding solution for differential equation with at least one known trivial solution
I was following the tutorial at SymPy site on how to solve differential equations, and started with the classic case of finding a function that equals its own derivative, as shown bellow:
from sympy import Function, dsolve, Derivative, symbols

y = Function('y')
x = symbols('x')
result = dsolve(Derivative(y(x), x) - y(x), y(x))
print(result)

It returns the exponential function, as expected:
Python 3.10.12 (main, Jul 29 2024, 16:56:48) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

=================== RESTART: /xxxx/xxxx/xxxxxxxxxx/eq_diff.py ==================
Eq(y(x), C1*exp(x))

Now I had the idea of trying to add a little tweak, to see if I can find some function that behaves like the exponential, but with "inertia" added. By inertia I mean, instead of f(x) equating its derivative at a given x, there's sort of a delay, and it will equate its derivative only at a further coordinate in the x axis, say, x + k, so the function would equate it's rate of change with a fixed delay of k units. So I tried to set this new system like:
from sympy import Function, dsolve, Derivative, symbols

y = Function('y')
x, k = symbols('x k')
result = dsolve(Derivative(y(x), x) - y(x + k), y(x))
print(result)

It doesn't look that different. But now it seems SymPy failed to find an solution. Instead, it appears to just present the initial equation in alternate form, by integrating both sides:
Python 3.10.12 (main, Jul 29 2024, 16:56:48) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

=================== RESTART: /xxxx/xxxx/xxxxxxxxxx/eq_diff.py ==================
Eq(y(x), C1 + Integral(y(k + x), x))

At first I thought perhaps SymPy didn't find an solution because my idea of an "exponential with inertia" simply doesn't exist. But pondering a bit, there's at least one trivial solution it should have found. For example, a constant function y = 0 will equate its own derivative - 0 - at any offset. So now I think I probably didn't set it properly. So I ask, where did I get it wrong, how can I set SymPy to solve it properly, and does a non-trivial solution for this exponential with inertia function exist?

DDEs are really a separate chapter from ODEs because of their specific solving techniques. AFAIK even the consecrated computer algebra software systems don't excel at solving DDEs symbolically, most only offer numerical solvers. The question about a similar DDE with sympy has been asked here on stackoverflow, you may check the references therein, especially this math stackexchange one about the actual solution.

Thank you, @kikon , this is a new concept for me. I knew about ODEs and PDEs, but had never heard about DDEs before.

In sympy, y(x) is not yevaluated at x, but it is just a compund symbol for a function y that depends on the variable x. Thus y(x+k) is incomprehensible and if it does not produce an error, then the workaround is most likely something unexpected, like an independent constant.
